# Downloading a public bucket from s3 without s3 tools (s3cmd)

Tags: amazon-s3

I'd like to download a complete repository from S3. I know the bucket is reachable at https://s3.amazonaws.com/big-data-benchmark/pavlo

I'd like everything under `/pavlo/sequence-snappy/5nodes`

How should one download this with the least amount of manual effort with readily available tools like wget? (The s3 tools require an actual s3 account, which I do not have and want.)

Answer (score 0):

Though a bit of manual effort is needed, this is how it can be done:

Goto the bucket http URL and add the `?marker=/pavlo/sequence-snappy/5nodes`, resulting in https://s3.amazonaws.com/big-data-benchmark/pavlo/sequence-snappy/5nodes

Now, binary search manually on how large the dataset it is. Fortunately, the listing of your specific bucket is predictable and it seems to have 100 items ranging from 000000_0-000099_0

Use the following shell one-liner:

```
for i in {0000..0099}; do echo https://s3.amazonaws.com/big-data-benchmark/pavlo/sequence-snappy/5nodes/rankings/00${i}_0; done | xargs -n1 -P8 wget
```

Preferably we would like a more general solution which would also work for unpredictable filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that the S3 tools do not require an account for anonymous access to public buckets.  (Nor do I understand why anyone wouldn't want a free account, but I digress.)

But here is a solution that works when the keys (paths/filenames) are not known or predictable:

If a bucket is truly public, as this one is, you'll find paginated XML list of all the keys at the root of the bucket.

`curl -v https://s3.amazonaws.com/big-data-benchmark/`, for example.

Each `<Key>` contains the path to an object.  This is the [List Objects V1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) API, so you add `?marker=` and the value of the last key in the listing, on the next request, to resume the listing, repeating the process until `<IsTruncated>` is no longer true.

Use this to build a list to pass to curl, wget, or your http client of choice, by appending the key to the bucket URL.  S3 can handle many, many parallel requests, so you may want to parallelize the process.

Comment: I have not been able to actually download anything with s3cmd from public buckets. It always asks to configure. As for a "free" account --  I have no intention to give Amazon my creditcard info (which is required), if I'm not going to buy anything in the first place.